# regex - multiple $1 by 10

Tags: regex

I want to replace the results of this:

```
(something=)([\-\d\.]*)
```

with this:

```
nowitis=($2*10)
```

but isntead of getting

```
nowitis=(80)
```

i get

```
nowitis=(8*10)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: Regex doesn't really support expression evaluation, you may want to specify what *language* you're using ...

Answer (score 0):

In sed, for example:

```
echo "something=123" | sed -r 's/(something=)([\-\d\.]*)/\1\2*10)/'
something=123*10)
echo "something=123" | sed -r 's/(something=)([\-\d\.]*)/\1\20/'
something=1230
```

Multiplication by 10 is just adding a Zero to the number. Sed doesn't calculate results.

However, all regex implementations I know of, can have it a bit more easy:

```
echo "something=123" | sed -r 's/(something=)([-\d.]*)/\1\20/'
something=0123
```

In the group [-\d.], the - sign is leading, so it can't be part of a range like A-Z. Well, it could, it could mean from \0 to something, but it doesn't. As first or last character, it doesn't need a mask.

Similarly, every group containing a dot, if dot was interpreted as a joker sign, could be reduced to just that jokersign. Therefore you don't need a joker like this in the group. So you don't have to mask it too.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you are on a POSIX system with Perl available.

```
echo "something= 8" | perl -pe 's/\w\s*=\s*\K-?\d+(\.\d+)?/$&*10/ge'
something= 80
```

What you want to do is not possible with regular regex because they cannot do arithmetic e.g. compute `8*10`. One way is to use an interpreter that can do so.

Perl has a nice feature which is the `e` switch. It evaluates the replacement pattern in which I do `$& * 10`, where `$&` is the captured pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The input string can be like:

```
something=10.2
something=-3.15
```

So there can be negative numbers and float numbers.

I have a PHPStorm IDE and I'm using its find&replace function with regex
So it is fine but no multiplication.
So I think I could do it in couple runs.
For example in next run I would find mine results and then move the dot by 1.
I read the PCRE docs and didn't find multiplication option.

Easier would be writing a script even in PHP to do it right.
But I thought it could be done easier.